# Identifying a UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

How do you identify a UIStoryboard?

The class has methods which create and instantiate but I don't see an @property with something like `name`. E.g.

Getting a Storyboard Object

```
+ storyboardWithName:bundle:
```

Instantiating Storyboard View Controllers

```
– instantiateInitialViewController
– instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
```

Any suggestions?

====
UPDATE

I was hoping for something like `self.storyboard.name` or `[self.storyboard description]`, e.g.:

```
NSLog(@"This Storyboard is: %@", self.storyboard.name);
```

Perhaps it's not meant to be.

Comment: It depends on where you're trying to identify it. If you're in a controller that was created in the storyboard, you just use self.storyboard. If you're doing it from the app delegate, or you need to get a reference to another storyboard (not the one your controller is in) then you need to use the method shown by Brian Luby in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can identify a storyboard by its name in the project navigator:

[image]

You can identify a view controller from a storyboard by setting its Storyboard ID in the identity inspector in interface builder:

[image]

Once you have these, then you can access them through your code:

```
UIStoryboard *iPhoneStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
ViewController *firstViewController = [iPhoneStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
```