# Is this a bug in Xcode 5 for iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

1. Create a new single-view project (e.g., 'Test')
2. Within the main storyboard, create two view controllers with titles `One` and `Two` - make `One` the initial view controller
3. Place the label `One` within the content of view controller `One` and label `Two` within `Two`
4. Include the following within the `viewDidLoad` of `TestViewController.m`:

   ```
   // instantiate the new view controller
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
   TestViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Two"];
   // Change the view
   viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
   [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```
5. Save, build, and run.

I consistently get an error of the `Storyboard does not contain view controller 'Two'` variety. Using breakpoints, I've discovered that the problem is at the instantiation step. Yet the above code is taken directly from Apple's View Controller Programming Guide.

I've combed this site and discovered many people having problems with instantiating view controllers programatically. Any definite solution?

Comment: When you say titles do you mean Storyboard ID because that is what is used by instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:?

Answer (score 0):

**There's no bug here -- you're just writing inappropriate code.** The code snippet you've given works fine if you put it in an action and trigger it with a button, a timer, etc. But you're attempting to present another view controller modally before the view controller running the code has even gotten around to displaying its own view.

`-viewDidLoad` is called when the view controller's view has been loaded from the storyboard or .xib file; it's an opportunity to do any initialization that had to be deferred until the view hierarchy comes into existence. However, the view isn't actually displayed at that point. You need to wait until you get a `-viewDidAppear` message to know that the view is on screen. So, you can imagine that it doesn't make a lot of sense to try to present some *other* view controller before the current one has even settled in.

> I consistently get an error of the Storyboard does not contain view controller 'Two' variety.

In that case, you haven't properly assigned a storyboard identifier to the view controller. Select  view controller "Two" in the storyboard editor and then look at the identity inspector. You need to set the identifier like this:

[image: identity inspector]

> I've combed this site and discovered many people having problems with
>   instantiating view controllers programatically. Any definite solution?

Did you also look at the answers to their questions? That's how this site works -- we answer questions not just for the people that are asking them, but also to help others in the future who may have similar questions. [Identifying a UIStoryboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16061624/643383) is a good example of a question similar to yours with an answer that probably would have helped you.